# Dans quelle langue répondre quand la question est posée à la fois en français et en anglais?

Tags: discussion, language

Il arrive des cas comme [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/23721/9176) où la personne pose la question à la fois en français et en anglais. Dans un tel cas, quel est le meilleur comportement à adopter ? Faut-il répondre en Français, en Anglais, dans les deux langues ? Ou est-ce une simple question de préférences ?

Je suis enclin à répondre qu'une réponse dans les deux langues serait idéale, mais ce n'est évidemment pas toujours simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On trouve la réponse sur la page d'aide du site ([fr](https://french.stackexchange.com/help), [en](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) :

> Vous pouvez répondre en français ou en anglais. Il est en général
>   préférable de répondre dans la même langue que la question, mais si
>   vous préférez répondre en français, vous pouvez.
>
> ---
>
> **Should I ask/answer in French or English?** Both languages are accepted. If you are learning French, we suggest that you learn by
>   doing and ask in French, but there is no obligation. Note that some
>   contributors prefer to answer in French, so you may get replies in
>   French. On the meta site, we try to provide at least a summary of each
>   post in both languages.

Le fait qu'une question soit posée dans les deux langues n'y change rien, à mon avis.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, j'ai posé la question dans les deux langues pour profiter de l'occasion pour travailler mon français, et pour communiquer avec les membres du site qui ne parlent pas anglais. Je serais heureux de recevoir des réponses dans une langue ou dans l'autre (Désolé, ce n'était probablement pas très clair.)

Comment: C'était clair, ne vous inquiétez pas ! Je posais simplement cette question afin de savoir si il y avait une manière définie ou préférable de répondre à des questions posées dans les deux langues à la fois. Votre question était très claire, et l'effort d'avoir traduit très sympathique.

Comment: J'ai édité la réponse pour corriger les fautes, et proposer d'autres formulations. "utiliser mon français" sonne faux, j'ai donc proposé "travailler" qui se rapproche plus de l'idée. "L'une et l'autre langue" sonne également faux, on dira "dans une langue ou dans l'autre" ou "dans l'une ou l'autre des langues" peut-être...

Comment: Concernant le fait d'écrire la réponse dans les deux langues, je ne pense pas que des membres aient du mal à lire l'anglais. Le plus compliqué est de l'écrire. Donc à mon avis, écrire la question dans les 2 langues joue 2 roles : Vous faire parler français (et en cas de mauvais français, la partie anglaise permet de comprendre ce que vous vouliez dire), et encourager les réponses en français (certains membres ne vont pas oser répondre à une question anglaise en français, de peur d'être incompris, car on ne connait pas le niveau en français de chacun)

Comment: @Random Il y a de fortes chances que des Français sur le site ou ailleurs aient du mal à lire l'anglais, contrairement à ce que vous pensez. En effet, le score [EF EPI 2016](http://mediakey1.ef.com/__/~/media/centralefcom/epi/downloads/full-reports/v6/ef-epi-2016-french.pdf) de la France la place 37e sur 72 avec un niveau de compétence _modéré_. Des types de tâches de niveaux supérieurs à _modéré_ incluent par exemple _lire un journal_ ou _comprendre des émissions de télévision_. De plus l'étude indique que les femmes ont un niveau de compétence supérieur aux hommes en moyenne...

Comment: @Random: Merci. Je suis d'accord avec votre deuxième commentaire.